# Trying to do arithmetic in Perl rename tool (Debian)

Tags: debian, rename, perl, arithmetic

Let's suppose I have five mp3 files:

```
01-trackfoo.mp3
02-trackbar.mp3
03-trackbaz.mp3
04-trackabc.mp3
05-trackxyz.mp3
```

Now I give a quick listen to the files (just mplayer on console will do the trick) and I find out that the tracks are in **wrong order**. 05 is actually 02 and the rest will have to be renamed. So first I will do a temp rename:

```
01-trackfoo.mp3

02-trackbar.mp3
03-trackbaz.mp3
04-trackabc.mp3
00-trackxyz.mp3
```

Now we need a "shift": 02 should become 03, 03 should become 04 and 04 should become 05. To minimize confusion, ex-05 (now 00) will just be `mv`ed later.

My approach was this: (perl `rename`, by Larry Wall, default here on Debian)

```
rename 's/0([2-4])([\s\S]+)/0($1+1)$2/' *
```

as well as (later, after some more RTFM'ing)

```
rename 's/0([2-4])([\s\S]+)/0($1+1)$2/e' *
```

None of them worked, especially because the `/e[val]` modifier does not accept anything else *but* evaluations, and will throw an error once you attempt to combine the evaluations with strings. The `bash` can do it just fine, e. g.  `foo$((1+6))` will be evaluated to `foo7`.

So how can I do this (one-liner preferred, not intending to write a whole standalone script just for this)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You almost had it. You just need to make literal strings and string concatenation explicit within the `/e`-modified substitution, using quotes and the dot operator.

```
rename 's/0([2-4])([\s\S]+)/"0".($1+1).$2/e' *
```

Comment: It leaves the original *05* still un-renamed, but +1 for resolving the *one-liner* glitch.

Comment: (minor note, *rename* is called *prename* in Ubuntu) ... If no names in the directory starts with `$'\x01'2` then a preliminary renaming like this: `prename 's/^05/\x012/' 05*` .. then the above `[2-4]` rename .. then a final `prename 's/^\x01/0/' $'\x01'2*` will do the trick.. That makes **3** one-liners... For a fourth, and an initial check for the possible presence of a file starting with `$'\x01'`, something like this *bash* snippet will trap it .. `shopt -s nullglob; x=($'\x01'*); [[ -n $x ]] && { echo '\x01' is not suitable; exit; }`

Comment: YEEES! Thank you Alan, I didn't think of that dot operator, though I did know what to do in human-readable words: "tell /e not to touch the stuff _outside_ the ( )" :) And thanks to Peter for the bash approach as well. Besides, if I had had any idea of _how_ close PHP syntax is to Perl's, I would probably have found the solution by trial-and error. Because that dot IS the JavaScript '+' counterpart in PHP for string concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

> one-liner preferred, not intending to write a whole standalone script just for this

When things get so complicated, I don't see any reason not to write a script. You're never going to remember how to do this from one run to the next, so you're going to end up either reinventing it each time, or wrapping it up in a script anyway.

For a small thing like this, I generally start trying to solve it in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ] ; then echo Need arguments. ; exit 1 ; fi

typeset -i i=1
for f in "$*"
do
    tailbits=`echo "$f" | sed -e 's/^[0-9]+//'`
    mv "$f" sertmp-`printf %02d $i`"$tailbits"
    i=i+1
done

for f in "sertmp-*"
do
    mv "$f" `echo "$f" | sed -e s/^sertmp-//` 
done
```

Basically, this script strips off any leading digits, then puts a zero-padded increasing serial number on the front, with the files numbered according to the order you pass them to the script.

It does this in two stages, with `sertmp-` prefixes for the first pass to avoid any risk of name collisions. If you call this script `mp3-renamer` and call it like:

```
$ mp3-renamer 01-foo.mp3 03-bar.mp3 04-qux.mp3
```

you run into a trivial collision on the first rename if you don't use 2 passes to do the renaming. (`01-foo.mp3` -> `01-foo.mp3`.)

If you call it like this, though:

```
$ mp3-renamer 02-foo.mp3 01-foo.mp3
```

you accidentally erase `01-foo.mp3` in the first rename with a 1-pass rename.

If the problem gets more complicated, I'd rewrite it in Perl. At that point, you could then use a hash to hold the old->new name mapping, and use a bit of clever code to work out the proper order to do the renamings in order to avoid the need for 2 passes.